# Issue downloading node.js v16

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I'm currently trying to update my vps server from node.js v15 to v16. But of course it doesn't work. I'm following this tutorial https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-debian/ but the system is still running on v.15.

I get an error while executing this command:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo bash -
```

Error:
[image: pic]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://askubuntu.com is a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install nvm in order to get it work! Here's the link...

```
https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-nvm-on-ubuntu-20-04/#:~:text=%20How%20To%20Install%20NVM%20on%20Ubuntu%2020.04,versions%20using%20nvm.%20And%20use%20the...%20More%20
```